# How to pass arguments to Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I define the arguments in the Dockerfile, but I want to build all my Dockerfiles uniformly through docker compose, if the argument values are passed into the Dockerfile through docker-compose build

- my Dockerfile

```
...

ARG ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE
RUN  dotnet build path/to/my/porject.csproj -c $ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE

...
```

- my docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
...

    my.image:
        image: myimage:123
        container_name: my.image
        build:
            context: ../../
            dockerfile: path/to/Dockerfile
            args:
                ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE: #{ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE}

...
```

Comment: Just pass the arguments while starting the container. During `docker run IMAGE ARGS`

Comment: One of the things I can see people struggle with, is distinguishing between what happens at build time and what happens at run-time. The way you've set yours up, it's impossible from the docker-compose file to see if your argument is runtime or build time. Personally I think the clearest way of doing things is doing builds outside of docker compose and only using docker compose to spin up images that are already built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use docker compose you can pass arguments like this.

```
docker-compose build --build-arg ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE=YOUR_VALUE
```

Is that what You mean with Your question?